# Reformat pandas DataFrame into a formal 1nf

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, database-normalization

If I have such a DataFrame that was made previously by a spreadsheets program

| Variable | Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 14.08. 21:00 | 1 | 123 | 3 |
| NaN | 07.08. 21:00 | 2 | 321 | 1 |
| Value2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 01.08. 20:00 | 1 | 132 | 2 |

Then I need to convert it to 1nf form of database within a piece of code to look like this

| Variable | Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | 14.08. 21:00 | 1 | 123 | 3 |
| Value1 | 07.08. 21:00 | 2 | 321 | 1 |
| Value2 | 01.08. 20:00 | 1 | 132 | 2 |

I've tried to do such a job within this code

```
def normalize(Series):
    x=""
    for value in Series:
        if pd.notna(value): 
            x=value
        elif pd.isnull(value):
            value=x
normalize(df['Variable'])
```

so it iterates over the series if the value of the cell not null then it saves the value into a variable to insert it every time there's a null afterwards then takes another value and so on, then later I can do `df.dropna()` to drop the rows that contained only variable value as a header and keep only the data

but it seems to be a little buggy it either won't change anything in the `df['variable']` or changes all of its values to `None` which are both not what I wanted to make

Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Comment: That transformation is not normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `ffill()` and `dropna()`:

```
df["Variable"] = df["Variable"].ffill()
df = df.dropna()

>>> df
  Variable          Date    A      B    C
1   Value1  14.08. 21:00  1.0  123.0  3.0
2   Value1  07.08. 21:00  2.0  321.0  1.0
4   Value2  01.08. 20:00  1.0  132.0  2.0
```